# How to feed object generated by sortable into a list, vector, or dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, sortablejs

I'm trying out R Shiny package `sortable`. I'm trying to feed the elements generated by the `bucket_list` in the reproducible code below into either a list, vector, or dataframe, to prepare for further data manipulation as I develop this. I have no idea what sort of object is generated by `bucket_list` below. Ideally, I need to strip out the numerical ranking (the 1 and 2 below) into one column and the Pool ID (B and A) into separate dataframe columns.

How can I feed those elements into a list/vector/dataframe? The image at the bottom better illustrates.

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)   

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      .column_2 {
        counter-reset: rank;                      
      }

      .column_2 .rank-list-item::before {
        counter-increment: rank;                   
        content: counter(rank) '. ';    
      }
    "))),
    htmlOutput("rankingForm"),
    tableOutput("table1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rankingForm <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(tags$b("Pool Ranking"), width = 12,
             bucket_list(header = "Drag to the right from the Pool below to rank.", 
                         group_name = "bucket_list_group", orientation = "horizontal",
                         add_rank_list("Pool:", 
                                       labels = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                                       input_id = "rank_list_1"),
                         add_rank_list("Pool Ranking:", labels = NULL,
                                       input_id = "rank_list_2"))
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({ranklist2})
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

Comment: `rank_list_2` is a vector of type character. You can access its value as `input$rank_list_2` (which you set via the `input_id` argument):  `output$table1 <- renderTable({input$rank_list_2})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working the solution incorporating yesterday's comment from I_O:

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)   

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
      .column_2 {
        counter-reset: rank;                      
      }

      .column_2 .rank-list-item::before {
        counter-increment: rank;                   
        content: counter(rank) '. ';    
      }
    "))),
    htmlOutput("rankingForm"),
    tableOutput("table1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rankingForm <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(tags$b("Pool Ranking"), width = 12,
             bucket_list(header = "Drag to the right from the Pool below to rank.", 
                         group_name = "bucket_list_group", orientation = "horizontal",
                         add_rank_list("Pool:", 
                                       labels = c("A","B","C","D","E"), 
                                       input_id = "rank_list_1"),
                         add_rank_list("Pool Ranking:", labels = NULL,
                                       input_id = "rank_list_2"))
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({input$rank_list_2}) # << solution
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```